# Reusing a function to handle 2 different data tyes as the 2nd argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to change my controller to handle 2 different query strings, but with the same number of arguments so it seems like i cannot have 2 functions with the same name and number of args:

Error

```
The current request for action 'FollowUp' on controller type 'ContactController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
```

so how do I do this?

****String #1 string,int ****
?contacted=true&id=7889876

**String #2 string,string**
?contacted=true&pid=AWRE-9876-POKJ-112WQ

**Current Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult FollowUp(string contacted, int id) {}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating two function make the single one with three arguments and use your logic in that accordingly.

**Example:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FollowUp(string contacted, string pid, int? id) 
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contacted) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pid)) {
      // do your logic.
   }
   else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contacted) && id != null) {
      // do your logic.
   }
}
```

**Note:** Taking `id` as `nullable` wouldn't require any value form URL. It will null if you don't pass anything to this argument.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than one action with the same name that can respond to a GET request. You can also add the other parameter to your action and decide what you will do by checking which parameters are present.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FollowUp(string contacted, int? id, string pid) {}
```